# Irreducible quartic curve in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $V$ be an irreducible quartic curve in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb{C})$. Then $V$ cannot have a point of multiplicity greater than or equal to $4$. Furthermore if $V$ has a triple point $(a,b,c)$, then $(a,b,c)$ is the only point on $V$ such that its multiplicity is greater than or equal to $2$.

How we defined the multiplicity of a point p via the Taylor expansion? We used Kirwan's book and called the smallest k such that a partial derivative does not vanish on the point.

What I tried so far was. Assume contradiction and let p be a point with multiplicity $\geq 4$. This implies that for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^ i \partial y^j \partial z^l} =0$ for $i+j+l=3$ and that for all $i+j+l\geq 4$ there is at least one partial derivative such that does not vanish. I am not sure how to derive this contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a line through the point of high multiplicity and any other point of the curve. Then use Bezout's Theorem.

A similar argument works for the triple point part, take a line through the triple point and a double point...

Comment: If I pick the point say p with multiplicity 4 and another point q on the curve say we make it multiplicity 1. Bezout's theorem will tell me a contradiction? Sorry I just learned about Bezout's theorem and to my knowledge it says for two Curves satisfying non degeneracy conditions that their degrees gets multiplied. Sorry for asking to spell out the argument I is a new adventure for me here =)

Comment: If the line goes through $p$ and $q$, then the curve and the line will meet $5$ times (4 times in $p$, and one time in $q$). This is a contradiction, because Bezout tells us, they will meet precisely $4$ times.

Comment: Apologies for the hobby-horsing, but I always feel like appealing to Bezout is overkill in the situation of intersecting with a _line_. Much simpler to say that a polynomial of degree $d$ in one variable (or a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in two variables) cannot have more than $d$ roots, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: This is a polynomial homogeneous in three variables.

Comment: But after intersecting it with a line, you get a homogenous polynomial in two variables.

Comment: I see a nice approach